# Create a Service using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I need to create a service using C# and **sc.exe** utility
when i try to execute

`C:\Windows\system32\sc.exe create ServiceName binPath= D:\work\ServiceExe.exe`,

it works fine. 
But when i try to execute

`Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\sc.exe create ServiceName binPath= D:\work\ServiceExe.exe");`

I have an exception, that **the system cannot find the file specified**.

What can it be?
File exists, Service removing before re-install.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use another overload of `Process.Start` which takes arguments as a separate parameter.

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\sc.exe", "create ServiceName binPath= D:\work\ServiceExe.exe")
```

Comment: How'd you do that if your location has spaces?

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding , you should create a deployment project for service which can  be made auto run and you donot need to bother after system restart/shutdown.