# Creating Service using a Process

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a new Windows Service by using `ProcessStartInfo` in .NET 4.6.1. The process is able to run but it is not actually creating the service itself.

```
var targetExe = Path.Combine(targetFolder, config.PackageDeploymentConfig.RuntimeExecutable);
const string sc = @"sc";
string arguments = $@"create {serviceName} binPath= ""{targetExe}"" start= ""demand"" obj= ""{username}"" password= ""{password}""";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo() {
  FileName = sc,
  Arguments = arguments,
  WorkingDirectory = serviceDrive,
  CreateNoWindow = true,
  UseShellExecute = false
};
var process = Process.Start(psi);
process.WaitForExit(waitForCompletionMs);
if (!process.HasExited) {
  throw new Exception("Unable to create service");
}
Console.WriteLine($"{serviceName} has been created");
```

It should create a new service, but it is not showing up in services. I am able to create a service using `cmd` using the same exact parameters. I'm thinking it might be a permission issue. If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: I know you don't want any window to open, but I'm wondering if creating the window/using shell execute make any difference?

Comment: I already tried using different parameters for the window/using shell. No difference :/

Comment: See if the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881901/create-a-service-using-c-sharp) fixes your problem.

Comment: Sc should be set to "cmd.exe"

Comment: @Icemanind unfortunately that didn't work. and setting it up cmd.exe just opens command prompt. sc is a command I can run on cmd.

Comment: @Jimbo check also `config.PackageDeploymentConfig.RuntimeExecutable` and `targetExe` contain correct paths

Comment: They all have the correct paths. I was able to run the command with the exact same parameters in command prompt and create the service.

Comment: @Jimbo did you try to run it under Administator?

Comment: @Jimbo also you can set `RedirectStandardOutput = true` in `psi` and add `Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());` after process started to check `sc` output

Comment: @VladimirP. let me try that. I think that'll work